# sql server join same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my Rows in a table :

```
Id    |       FromDate            |       ToDate             | prod_Id
------|---------------------------|--------------------------|-------
1     |   2012-08-13 07:00:00.000 |  2012-08-14 18:59:00.000 |    10
1     |   2012-08-13 07:00:00.000 |  2012-08-15 18:59:00.000 |    10
1     |   2012-08-13 07:00:00.000 |  2012-08-16 18:59:00.000 |    10
```

I would like a result like below:

```
Id  |   FromDate                  |        ToDate             | prod_Id
----|-----------------------------|---------------------------|---------
1   |    2012-08-13 07:00:00.000  |   2012-08-16 18:59:00.000 |   10
```

How to do it?

Comment: can u be more specific sir? any criteria for getting the result so anybody can help

Comment: We have no idea what your current query looks like, nor what relationship exists between your current result and desired result. At the moment, the query `SELECT 1,'2012-08-13T07:00:00.000','2012-08-16T18:59:00.000',10` would be an "answer".

Answer (score 5):

```
 SELECT Id, MIN(FromDate), MAX(ToDate), prod_Id
 FROM TbName
 GROUP BY Id, prod_Id
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, try this sql.
i think that is what you want.

```
SELECT Id, FromDate, MAX(ToDate), prod_Id
FROM TbName
GROUP BY Id, FromDate, prod_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go in the following way

```
SELECT
p.dept,p.id,
u.FirstName +'+ ' '+ '+ u.LastName as CreatedBy,                            
v.FirstName +'+ ' '+ '+ v.LastName as ModifiedBy
from tblUserNew p
inner join tblUserNew u on p.CreatedBy=u.Id
inner join tblUserNew as v  on p.ModifiedBy=v.Id
```